# How to disable sticky edges if the switch in the displays configuration window does not help?

Tags: window-manager, 15.10

There is an on/off switch for sticky edges in the display settings window. But toggling it does not seem to change anything at all. How do I disable sticky edges then? I'm running 15.10.

Comment: I'm having the same problem on Ubuntu 15.10 with 3 monitors. The problem seems triggered when I have one or more terminal windows open.  If I cross the monitor boundary at a vertical position (y-value) where there are no windows, the mouse doesn't stick.   Tried lots of tweaks but no solution so far!  :(